# Scikit-learn: getting same result on all rows when reusing the model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I want to figure out some GDP numbers from a country's GDP primary industry. The earliest data does not have any GDP values so I have trained a model with newer data. My plan is to use that trained model to guess older data.

I then fed new data to the model (the older data) but the model predicts the same number value for all the years!

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I only started with ML so apologies for messy code/ml technique :(

EDIT: FIXED. The new data needed to be scaled too :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to call `sc.transform` on `X1` as well. Otherwise, the scale of the features would be off, and the predictions become erroneous too.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I still get the same results in all predicted rows.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. It worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **sklearn** [`Pipelines`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html) (also [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)) to take care of rescaling the data before new use for you.